# exe file puts error: "ps.1 not digitally signed"

Tags: windows, powershell, exe

I keep failing installing [Teradici](https://www.teradici.com/) via installer exe file, and the error says:

```
PCoIP Graphics Agent requires port 60443, but it is being used by process
". : File C:\Users\user\OneDrive\문서\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\user\OneDrive\문서\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 is not digitally signed.

You cannot run this script on the current system.
For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

At line:1 char:3

+ . 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\문서\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_p ...

+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess".  Stop process ". : File C:\Users\user\OneDrive\문서\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 cannot be loaded.
The file C:\Users\user\OneDrive\문서\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 is not digitally signed.
```

It seems to be Powershell ExecutionPolicy problem, so I tried `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`, and this is the result:

[image]

And it didn't work. I also tried to execute the exe file through powershell (run as admin) directly and also didn't work. How can I bypass the error message? The `ps1` script is not run by me, but run by the exe file itself.

Comment: I would concentrate on the PORT error.  The second error just indicates a failure of getting the profile.  The port could be blocked by a virus checker or a Firewall.  Use the following to get a list of used ports and check for 60443 : Get-NetTCPConnection